# SDL2 error messages won't go away

Tags: c++, windows, compiler-errors, mingw, sdl-2

Compile command/what's in the .bat:

```
g++ -o program.exe SME.cpp -w -Wl -subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
pause >nul
```

SME.cpp:

```
#include "SDL2\SDL.h"

int main()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

- I have build.bat, SME.cpp and SDL2.dll in a folder
- MinGW is in the default C:\MinGW directory
- I installed MinGW using the installer
- I added C:\MinGW\include
- I put the SDL2 header files in C:\MinGW\include\SDL2\
- I put the SDL2 library files (SDL2main.lib and SDL2.lib) in C:\MinGW\lib.
- I added C:\MinGW\bin to the Path variable
- I've solved all of the previous problems by looking on the internet for answers to them

The compiler keeps complaining that there is an undefined reference to SDL_Init and SDL_Quit and that ld.exe (I have no idea what that is) has returned exit status 1 due to an undefined reference to @WinMain16.

I've searched everywhere and there is a short supply of answers to this problem and all of the answers I've come across haven't worked. I've tried 3 different ways of doing this: with a .bat, with a Makefile and with Eclipse. It always comes down to these three errors. I have no idea what is going wrong, I checked and SDL_init.h and SDL_quit.h both exist. I don't know what @WinMain16 is either.

Comment: I haven't used "vanilla" mingw in some time now but I don't remember having to use all of those flags on the command line. Fwiw with mingw-w64 it should just work with `g++ -o program.exe SME.cpp -lSDL2`, you'll also have the added bonus of using a more recent compiler.

Comment: Try `g++ -o program.exe SME.cpp -LC:\MinGW\lib -w -Wl -subsystem,windows -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`

Comment: I tried your suggestions just now, same errors and nothing new :/ I'm gonna try putting SDL2's include and lib files in folders and then referencing them directly one last time

Comment: That didn't work; same errors, nothing new.